# Interleaved insertion sort function doesn't sort correctly

Tags: c++

I have this function that is supposed to use insertion sort interleaving to prepare an array for shell sorting. I was testing the `insertionSortInterleaved()` function as stated below:

```
void insertionSortInterleaved(int numbers[], int numbersSize, int startIndex, int gap) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (i = i + gap; i < numbersSize; i += gap) {
        j = i;
        while (j - gap >= startIndex && numbers[j] < numbers[j - gap]) {
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j - gap];
            numbers[j - gap] = temp;
            j = j - gap;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the main, I made an array of the numbers 1-20, but in descending order, then I made it print out each element of the array. I then made the main insertionSort the array and return the array again after sorting.

```
int main() {
    int numbers[] = { 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    insertionSortInterleaved(numbers, 20, 1, 5); //numbers being the array, 20 being the amount of numbers being sorted, 1 being the starting index, and 5 being the gap space)
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        cout << numbers[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs the original array just fine, but after the "sorting," it outputs the array in the same order as the first time.
Before: `20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`
After:  `20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

After sorting, shouldn't the numbers be in ascending order? If so, what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In `while (j - gap >= startIndex || numbers[j] < numbers[j - gap])` use || operator. index + gap can also lead to out-of-range error watch out. I changed i = 0 in the for loop for that matter.

```
void insertionSortInterleaved(int numbers[], int numbersSize, int startIndex, int gap) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numbersSize; i += gap) {
        j = i;
        while (j - gap >= startIndex || numbers[j] < numbers[j - gap]) { // changed Here
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[j - gap];
            numbers[j - gap] = temp;
            j = j - gap;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int numbers[] = { 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    insertionSortInterleaved(numbers, 20, 1, 1); //numbers being the array, 20 being the amount of numbers being sorted, 1 being the starting index, and 1 being the gap space)
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        cout << numbers[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In a function signature, `int []` is equivalent to `int *`

Comment: @seccpur I kind of got it. the output after the sort is now `5 19 18 17 16 10 14 13 12 11 15 9 8 7 6 20 4 3 2 1`. It's still kind of messed up though

Comment: @seccpur sorry, I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: Call insertionSortInterleaved(numbers, 20, 1, 1) instead of insertionSortInterleaved(numbers, 20, 1, 5) otherwise you will skip sorting all the values.

Comment: @seccpur i gotcha. The thing is, the test in the assignment has it set to 5. That's why I have it as 5 in the program

Comment: @JohnSmith This looks a lot like a shell sort, and in a shell sort the gaps decrease as the algorithm proceeds. Make sure the instructor didn't specify an array of gaps.

Comment: @user4581301 it is shell sort, but we do have to use this function in the shell sort function

Comment: In that case, make sure it is correct for one iteration. By itself, this function will not completely sort UNLESS the gap size is 1.